# Collect outlook email responses as tasks and populate in excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, task

would appreciate any help / suggestions

I'm very new to VBA & macros. I work in administration and I have a lot of interrelated tasks and I would like to speed up the process a bit.

I receive an approval email from managers telling me which items a new employee will need / is approved for when they start. I then need to create a task/reminder for each item I need to remember to organise for this employee and transfer all of the responses across to a tracking spreadsheet on a shared drive so that we can track the applications / items for the new employee.

What would be great is if I could set up a rule so that automatically when I receive one of these emails a task is created for each individual item with a "yes" and ignored for "no" and all the "yes / no " responses are populated into the next available single row in the excel sheet. Even better would be if when I mark the task in outlook as "completed" it transferred this info to the excel sheet - this might be wishful thinking.

For example the email might look like this:

```
Employee Name: John Doe
Line Manager: Jane Smith
Start Date: 1/1/2012 
Item 1: Yes
Item 2: No
Item 3: Yes
Item 4: Yes
```

And the excel would have a column for each of the above.

Again - any assistance / suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg100610-story01.html) really helps with the automation of handling incoming mail and I highly recommend you read the tips on getting Outlook VBA working there.

This code is slightly adapted from that page. Comment lines starting with TODO still need to be filled in but this should get you started on the right track.

```
Option Explicit
'
' Place this code in the "ThisOutlookSession" class module
'
' The code will:
'
' Monitor the Inbox
' Check for the existence of a specific kind of e-mail
' Move the processed e-mail to a "processed" folder
'
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

'
' Application_Startup() is a reserved function that will automatically
' be called when Outlook starts.
'
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

'
' This event is fired when the Inbox receives a new message
' (it can also be fired when manually moving a message from
'  another folder back to the inbox)
'
Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

'    On Error Resume Next (commented out for ease of debugging)

    Dim olMailItem As MailItem
    Dim strAttachmentName As String
    Dim Employee() As Variant
    Dim v() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NumItems As Long
    Dim line As Variant
    '
    ' Only inspect mail items
    ' Ignore appointments, meetings, tasks, etc.
    '
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set olMailItem = Item
        '
        ' Test for specific subject line
        '
        If InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "My Subject Line") > 0 Then
            ' Get an array of lines in the body of the email
            v = Split(olMailItem.Body, vbCrLf) 

            ' TODO Parse the array for the data required to populate your Excel file
            ' TODO Open (or activate) the Excel file
            ' TODO Add the data to the Excel file

            ' Once complete, move mail item to OK/Errors folder
            ' This code assumes the folders already exist
            ' and are subfolders of the Inbox folder
            '
            ' In older versions of Outlook, olDestFolder
            ' should be declared as type MAPIFolder
            ' instead of Folder
            '
            Dim olDestFolder As Folder, strFolderName As String
            If Err.Number Then
                strFolderName = "Processed_Errors"
            Else
                strFolderName = "Processed_OK"
            End If
            '
            ' Display Message
            '
            Set olDestFolder = _
                Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(strFolderName)
            If Err.Number Then
                olMailItem.Move olDestFolder
                MsgBox Err.Description + strFolderName + vbCrLf + _
                       "Check the error folder", _
                       vbCritical, "Automated e-Mail processing unsuccessful"
            Else
                olMailItem.Move olDestFolder
                MsgBox "Message has been processed and placed in " + strFolderName, _
                        vbInformation, "Automated e-Mail processing successful"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set olMailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```